# how to parse response json from two different api calls ,but has same dictionary names with different values in a nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

I want to parse response json from two different api calls ,but has same dictionary names with different values in a nested for loop

I was able to get from the first api call, but failing on second api call with same dict as issues in both call but the key values are different.

```
def classtest(self):
    apione = "http://jira.com/rest/1"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
              } 
    requestglobal = requests.request("GET", apione, headers=headers)
    responseglobal = requestglobal.text
    responseglobal = json.loads(responseglobal)
    for i in responseglobal['issues']:
         issue1 = i[key]
         print(issue1)
         apitwo = "https://jira.com/rest/2" + str(issue1)
         requesttwo = requests.request("GET", apitwo, headers=headers)
         responsetwo = requesttwo.text
         responsetwo = json.loads(responsetwo)
         for i in responsetwo['issues']:
               issue2 = i[key] + str(issue1)
               print(issue2)
               apitthree = "https://jira.com/rest/3" + str(issue1) + str(issue3)
               requestthree = requests.request("GET", apitthree, headers=headers)
               responsethree = requestthree.text
               responsethree = json.loads(responsetthree)
               for i in responsethree['issues']:
                     issue3 = i[key] + str(issue2) 
                     print(issue3)
               print("something from thirdloop")
         print("something from second loop") 
    print ("something from first for loop")
```

I want all the issues from all three api calls.